# adding images to laravel blades

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I m facing strange issue in laravel.

on my local serve it is not accessing this image
http://localhost:8000/img/logo.png

but I can acess this image
http://localhost:8000/img/profile.png

mover over it is not show in code as well any ideas.

Comment: Post your code, please...

Comment: where do you place the images physically on drive? they are under public folder?

Comment: I m placing images in pubic folder. the strange thing is that i can access old images but unable to access newly added images

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<img src="{{ url('img/yourimage.png') }}" alt="">`

It will grab the image from your project `public` folder. It will look like `yourwebsite.com/img/yourimage.png` and in local server it will look like

```
http://localhost:8000/img/yourimage.png
```

**2nd Solution:**

Try

```
 {{ Html::image('yourimage.png') }}
```

Comment: I have tried both methods. But, the main think is that it is not accessing the images

Comment: Html is an obsolete facade, it's not supported any more.

Comment: @ahmadrabbani your images are in public folder? or in public/img ?

Comment: Yes Laravel 5.2, you can check my product on CodeCanyon here https://codecanyon.net/item/rms-laravel-result-management-system/17098010 i have used in it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel there is a inbuilt function url() which is used to ge the path from the public folder of your project. So to show image in your view you can use:

```
<img src="{{ url('img/yourimage.png') }}" alt="No image found">
```

Comment: I m using the same url method. but unable to find required resources/image

Comment: In that case you just paste the full url including the name.ext of image in browser address bar and check your image is accessible or not?

Comment: I have done this but unable to access image in browser but I can access older images in the same directory